# ASP MVC4 & Oracle DB: how to find out what's causing inline sql so slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection

I have a page with 129 queries where one of them is an inline sql query and the rest are generated by LINQ. 
I took a look on their performance using Glimpse. Their query execution time is good but the connection opened time is too long, in particular the inline one.
What's causing this or how can I trace this? 
*I am pretty new to MVC4 and oracle

Example of the sql trace from glimpse:

[image: Example of the sql trace from glimpse]

1st row is by LINQ, query exec: 0.65 ms, conn open time: **1.66ms** (other rows by LINQ has similar performance to this one)

2nd row is inline SQL, query exec: 0.54 ms, conn open time: **3277.73ms**

I have one DB context per controller so AFAIK it should only use one DB connection.

Comment: 129 queries on one page? What do you mean by "connection time"? Are you opening and closing 129 connections on the same request, or do you have a per-request instance?

Comment: Try in connection string add np: This becomes `Server=np:server\instance` and forces the Named Pipes instead of the default of TCP. but still 129 connection for one request is not a good idea

Comment: It is what the Glimpse said. Those queries except one were generated by LINQ. I was also surprised by the number but they are not slow. 

About the connection time, I mean the connection open time that is shown by Glimpse. 

About the opening and closing, I am not sure what do you mean. I didn't even coded to open one. The EF/LINQ handle it I think.